# Gtk# and Xamarin running Mono, executable file won't load on Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, xamarin, exe, monodevelop, gtk#

I made a very simple stopwatch program with Gtk# using Xamarin, which I [uploaded on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheiPilat/LeAmazingStopwatch).

It runs smoothly when I build it from Xamarin, but the released .exe won't load when double-clicking it. It can be run from Mono command prompt, though, running '**mono LeAmazingStopwatch.exe**'

Console applications built with Xamarin open without any problems, after countless searches I am convinced that it is the Gtk# that causes it.

I have spent 3 days in a row trying to solve this problem and I am about to get very, very depressed...

I checked lots of materials online, including Xamarin forums and StackOverflow, and basically tried all the solutions I've found:

1. Marking references as 'Local'
2. Building with .Net 4.0 Client Profile as target framework (and others) instead of default Mono / .Net 4.5
3. Checking and updating path variables
4. Reinstalling everything and starting from scratch

The problem is similar to [this one](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22792/generated-exe-file-not-working), but unlike the person starting the discussion, I was not that lucky.

Please help or I will loose my mind. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error is reported? Anything the event log? The normal problem with GTK# apps is that the path to the gtk dlls needs to be on the path, otherwise you need to write some clever setup code to find gtk and add it to the path inside your program.

Comment: Dear Matt, thanks a lot for clarifying, I've put the executable in the C:/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin and it solved it. Before I was putting it in .../2.12/lib/gtk-sharp-2.0. Thank you really a lot, I can't believe I've spent so much time in this loop!..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the quick response of [Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268874/matt-ward), the engineer from Xamarin, the answer was found: the problem is solved by placing the gtk dlls on the path to the executable; else you need to write some clever setup code to find gtk and add it to the path inside your program. Thank you again, kind sir!